# VBA Conditional Formatting Data Bar "Percent/Progress"

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

Basically, I am trying to do this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGzz7.jpg

(three pictures)

So I recorded a macro (with intent to clean it up later!) I want the cell data bar to essentially be the size of the percent that is in the cell.

I receive this as the recording.

```
Range("H439:H445").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).ShowValue = True
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueLowestValue
    .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueHighestValue
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarColor
    .Color = 49407
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Direction = xlContext
Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
Selection.FormatConditions(1).BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.Color
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

I received this code repeated multiple times from the recording, but upon searching for answers I realize it is an excel bug or problem/error.  However I feel that my problem is the *xlConditionValueHighestValue* (and lowest) part.  Another part of the code that was recorded shows xlAutomaticMax/xlAutomaticMin in it's place.

When I run the one part of the code (the posted part), it doesn't fill up based on the Max/Min value I entered (1, 0). Instead it takes the highest number (in this case the 33%) and fills that cell all the way. 
When I change that part to:

```
With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
       .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=0
       .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=1
    End With
```

I get a 
"Run-time error '1004': 
Application-defined or object-defined error"
that highlights the

```
.MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=1
```

line, so it likes the 0 line.  However I do not know the proper coding procedure to get it to do what I want and I have not found anything on the forums that uses the maxpoint or minpoint formula line, otherwise I would try to copy their notation.  Anybody know how to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
 With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=0
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:=1
 End With
```

Alternatively, you might stick with what you have but include a hidden row with a value of `1`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Just couldn't find the code for it! Thanks a bunch! 

PS. I had seen the hidden row trick but I want to avoid that as much as possible just to avoid complicating things with the rest of my code.